# Blender does not recognize imagemagick to run Bligify

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to run the Bligify extension, but he asked me to install gifsicle and imagemagik, I installed both using linux commands

apt-get install gifsicle
apt-get install imagemagick

but still, blender doesn't recognize imagemagik, I installed it using the debian app store, but it still doesn't work, I don't know what else to do.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Edit `~/.config/blender/*/scripts/addons/bligify/__init__.py` file, search for `default_magick_path = ""` variable and set your value to `$ which convert` output (in my system, the output is `/usr/bin/convert`).